# How to draw a line for end of the page?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on Jasper Reports. In my reports, I want to have the border style like below for my data

```
 ______ ______ ______ ______
|__H1__|__H2__|__H3__|__H4__|  
|      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      | 
|      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      | 
|______|______|______|______|

----------Page Footer--------
```

I would like to get the bottom border for the last line of every page. What I am currently getting is something like

```
 ______ ______ ______ ______
|__H1__|__H2__|__H3__|__H4__|  
|      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      | 
|      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |
```

There needs to be a gap from the footer so I cannot use a line in the page footer. Also If I do use a line in the page footer, the last row of the report will not have a bottom border.

Is there a way to conditionally enable the Bottom border based on the row being the last row of the page?

[image: screenshot of the report]

Answer (score 4):

Draw the line then `columnFooter` Band and set `isFloatColumnFooter="true"`

> `isFloatColumnFooter=true`, render column footer just below the last detail or group footer on that particular column

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_8" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="28bc671c-47fc-4083-8211-a3f952643349">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="5 empty records"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="1">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="300" height="1" uuid="226f98ce-bb08-4741-a5af-3073ce2aee3a"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="150" y="0" width="150" height="30" uuid="5279e4bc-05ce-46d7-b4cf-ef703d105d92">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box padding="5">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field " + $V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="30" uuid="96e9515f-fab2-483d-926b-6bc799199562"/>
                <box padding="5">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="1" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="300" height="1" uuid="226f98ce-bb08-4741-a5af-3073ce2aee3a"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output** (running with a 5 record empty datasource)

[image: Result]

> Note, when creating reports as invoice's etc, with fix
>   lines on page (that does not depend on datasource) the
>   `background` band can be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response. I tried your suggestions and it works well on all pages except in the last page as the Column Footer is displayed after the summary. Is there a way to not display the Column Footer on the last page?

Comment: @PrakashAr there is an attribute on jasperReport tag, isSummaryNewPage="true"  and you also have isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="false" try these.